# jQuery face detection and css

Tags: jquery, css, image, detect

my question is very hard and I hope someone can help me to solve this problem.

I'm building a website where people can upload images.

These images in some pages are in **vertical** thumbnails but they can upload orizzontal images as well.

The images in thumbnails are shown as background, and not in a img tag!

All that I would like to do is:

Detect the face in the image and set the background-position in order to be centered in the thumbnail.

I hope someone know how to do something like that!

PS: Why the image is in background? Couse of round corner -moz-, -webkit- and css3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is not really suited to intensive tasks such as image processing. If you insist, you could use canvas, which I think gives access to each pixel - but you wouldn't want to do the processing on-the-fly.

You'd be best processing the image server-side, then passing some coordinates to the browser (to identify the position of the face) and positioning the image with js.

Comment: there is this useful plugin: http://papermashup.com/jquery-face-detection/ I would like to use this algorithm with Background position instead of "top, left" positioning...